# Workflow for onboarding new hire employees

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-entra-id, azure-workflow-automation

I have successfully established and executed the onboarding workflow for new employees. I received an email containing a temporary access pass and username upon completion. I want to include the User Principal Name (UPN) details in this email. Could you guide me on how to add these details? Also, could you give me some insight on how to specify additional arguments using Microsoft Graph? I appreciate your help.